# Help with identifying a PCB header connector

Tags: pcb, hardware, plug, socket

I have scoured the Internet trying to locate what this is - I'd appreciate any information if someone recognizes this plug/socket combination. It is currently used to carry 5V DC power of about 1A.

The only identification is on the plug. There are two strings of characters on the plug: *5284* and *MK136*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Measure pitch of the pins, this will help a lot. Also, overall dimensions would be useful too.

Comment: Does the PCB have any markings on? Might be easier to find the board and look up the connector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That header is a Molex 2.50mm pitch SPOX wire to board header system. There are also several other manufacturers that make clones of these. Here is the Molex data sheet for the 4-pin shrouded PC mount header. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/276/0099990988_PCB_HEADERS-137537.pdf

This particular one has inline pins for through hole mount. There are also versions of the headers that have staggered pins where the part mounts to the PCB.

Here is the generic series image of the SPOX header:

[image]

You can purchase these online from Mouser Electronics at www.mouser.com

Mating cable end parts with crimp style pins are also available from Mouser.